# TIdTCPServer's TIdContext->Data odd behaviour

Tags: c++builder, indy

To send data to multiple clients I create a `TIdThreadSafeStringList` in `OnConnect` and assign it to `AContext->Data` like so

```
AContext->Data = new TIdThreadSafeStringList
```

When the client disconnects, its stringlist is deleted in `OnDisconnect` like so

```
delete AContext->Data
```

However this results in an AV. If I zero the parameter, like so

```
delete AContext->Data
AContext->Data = NULL
```

the AV goes away. Is there some auto cleanup I'm not aware of?

Using C++ Builder 10.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some auto cleanup I'm not aware of?

Yes.  `TIdContext` derives from `TIdTask`, which owns the `Data` property.  The `TIdTask` destructor is called after the `OnDisconnect` event and will free the `Data` object if it is not `NULL`.

Another (preferred) way to handle this situation is to instead derive a new class from `TIdServerContext` and add your `TIdThreadSafeStringList` to that class (and any other per-client custom functionality you want), eg:

```
class TMyContext : public TIdServerContext
{
public:
    TIdThreadSafeStringList *MyList;

    __fastcall TMyContext(TIdTCPConnection *AConnection, TIdYarn *AYarn, TIdContextThreadList *AList = NULL)
        : TIdServerContext(AConnection, AYarn, AList)
    {
        MyList = new TIdThreadSafeStringList;
    }

    __fastcall ~TMyContext()
    {
        delete MyList;
    }

    //...
};
```

Then assign your class type to the server's `ContextClass` property at runtime before activating the server, eg:

```
__fastcall TMyForm::TMyForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    IdTCPServer1->ContextClass = __classid(TMyContext);
    //...
}
```

Then, you can simply type-cast any `TIdContext*` pointer belonging to the server to your class type in order to access the `TIdThreadSafeStringList` (or other functionality):

```
static_cast<TMyContext*>(SomeIdContext)->MyList->...
```

This way, you can ignore the `TIdContext::Data` property altogether, or use it for other purposes, if desired.

Comment: "The TIdTask destructor is called after the OnDisconnect event and will free the Data object if it is not NULL." - I read that (except the last part about it not being NULL) but didn't understand. How can it free the object if it can't know what it is?

Comment: @MikeVersteeg it doesn't need to know the object's type. All objects derive from `TObject`, and `TObject` has a virtual destructor. `Data` is a `TObject` pointer, and freeing an object via a base `TObject` pointer is a safe operation, the object will be destroyed properly regardless of its actual type. This is one of the key features of polymorphism.